# How do I integrate Flutter web with Firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-web

I need to integrate my Flutter web app with Firebase. I found information, but it is all about Flutter for mobile apps and I need it for Flutter for web.

Answer (score 4):

[Flutter web](https://flutter.dev/web) is currently in a preview phase, which means that [it "does not have a plugin system yet."](https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web/blob/master/README.md).

Issues on GitHub about this have already been opened. Consider [this one](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32637).

The alternative it proposes for now is to [use the Dart web version of Firebase](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase).

For more information you should consider reading through the issues on GitHub.
This should help you to [**get started**](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32637#issuecomment-491968219) for now.

Comment: It is mean you want to create backend api for firebase, and you can call api any platform..Am I roght?

Answer (score 2):

The [FlutterFire library](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/FlutterFire.md) wraps the native Firebase SDKs for iOS and Android, and is not available for the [Flutter for the Web](https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web) at the moment.

There is however a [community library `firebase-dart`](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-dart) that wraps some of the Firebase products for Dart/Web users. From recent commits it seems that this library may be compatible with Flutter for the Web.

Comment: It is mean you want to create backend api for firebase, and you can call api any platform..Am I roght?

Answer (score -5):

Integrate Flutter project with Firebase:

Step 1: Firebase Setup. Visit Firebase official site Here. Click on GO TO CONSOLE.
Step 2: Add App to Project.
Step 2.1: Integrate Firebase into iOS. Open your Flutter project. ...
Step 2.2: Integrate Firebase into Android. The easiest way to get the Android App Id is navigate to the build.gradle file.

Comment: This is unrelated to the question as the question does not mention neither Android nor iOS.